# Calling API data, is accusing the [] was called on null

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

I'm trying to call an API, the console brings me the data, but on the screen it says that the method [] is being called as null.

How can I solve this?

```
body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: StreamBuilder<ApiResponse<CategoryResponse>>(
                stream: categoryBloc.subject.stream,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ApiResponse<CategoryResponse>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 5,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int data) {
                          return Card(
                              child: Column(children: <Widget> [
                                ListTile(leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.data.Result.image_url),
                                ),
                                  title: Text(snapshot.data.data.Result.name),
                                ),
                              ],
                              ),
                                );
                        },
                        );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  }
                  return Center(child: ColorLoader());
                }
            )
        )
```

I'm following this method of assembling the methods and the like to call from the API: https://github.com/iamsahilarora/Flutter-clean-architecture

Look at the console:

[image: console]

Comment: if you have a list you need to check the index of that list and make sure the internal values are not null

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.data.data.Result` with `.data[data].Result`.